# What Http Status Code HERE api returns after 250k transactions is used up?

Tags: here-api

I'm using a freemium account to test Routing API. I wonder what http status code and error message the api returns after 250k free transactions are burnt out?

I didn't find it in the documentation https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/http-status-codes.html.

Comment: 429 Too Many Requests, most likely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response will be as follows : error code will be 403, better to keep check like

```
if (status > 299) {
                InputStream is = con.getErrorStream();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                rd.close();
            }
```

{"error":"Forbidden","error_description":"These credentials do not authorise access. Please contact your customer
representative or email locationapi@here.com to discuss upgrading your account."}